# Splitting a String into an array with a specific amount of characters per element

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to be able to split a string such as

```
"AUGCUGAUGCCUAGUCUGC"
```

into an array

```
[ "AUG", "CUG", "AUG", "CCU", "AGU", "CUG" ]
```

such that each array element contains exactly three characters.

Is there any way to do this in an efficient, readable manner?

Answer (score 8):

Using [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) is one way:

```
"AUGCUGAUGCCUAGUCUG".scan(/.../)
#=> ["AUG", "CUG", "AUG", "CCU", "AGU", "CUG"]
```

The regex `/.../` matches 3 characters.

Comment: Depending on requirements, `r=/...|.{1,2}$/` may be preferred. If `s="abcdefg"`, `s.scan r #=> ["abc", "def", "g"]`, whereas `s.scan /.../ #=>  ["abc", "def"]`.

Comment: For that matter, use `/.{1,3}/` instead of `/...|.{1,2}$/`. Because the pattern is greedy it'll always grab blocks of three characters until only one or two are left, when it will return the remainder.

Comment: @theTinMan, good point. I noticed `$` wasn't needed, but your suggestion is better.

Comment: I see the point of you both, however, in OP's example, it's expected to throw away the remaining elements.

Comment: I didn't notice previously that the last letter was being abandoned. Nevertheless, I thinks it's useful to consider how the regex would be changed if you wanted to keep those extra characters. I can attest that there is educational value in doing so, as I learned something useful from @theTinMan's comment.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the fastest way to do this is to use [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack), which is the core method for tearing apart binary strings.

Something like:

```
str = "AUGCUGAUGCCUAGUCUGC"
str.unpack('A3' * (str.size / 3))
# => ["AUG", "CUG", "AUG", "CCU", "AGU", "CUG"]
```

Note that `unpack` will drop the trailing `"C"` because the line isn't an even 3-character boundary:

```
str.size # => 19
```

That can be fixed using:

```
str.unpack('A3' * (str.size / 3) + 'A*')
# => ["AUG", "CUG", "AUG", "CCU", "AGU", "CUG", "C"]
```

What is `'A3' * (str.size / 3)` doing you ask?

```
'A3' * (str.size / 3) # => "A3A3A3A3A3A3"
```

Regarding the speed: `unpack` is fast. It's a bit arcane to understand the format string but it can be well worth the time to learn it:

```
require 'fruity'

STR = "AUGCUGAUGCCUAGUCUGC"

UNPACK_FORMAT_STR = 'A3' * (STR.size / 3) + 'A*'

compare do
  unpack1 { STR.unpack('A3'*(STR.size/3) + 'A*') }
  unpack2 { STR.unpack(UNPACK_FORMAT_STR) }
  scan_it { STR.scan(/.{1,3}/) }
end
# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> unpack2 is faster than unpack1 by 60.00000000000001% ± 10.0%
# >> unpack1 is faster than scan_it by 2.6x ± 0.1
```

You can see the affect of precomputing `UNPACK_FORMAT_STR`, because `unpack2` is about 60% faster than `unpack1` only because of precomputing the value.

Increasing the size of `STR`:

```
STR = "AUGCUGAUGCCUAGUCUGC" * 1000

UNPACK_FORMAT_STR = 'A3' * (STR.size / 3) + 'A*'

compare do
  unpack1 { STR.unpack('A3'*(STR.size/3) + 'A*') }
  unpack2 { STR.unpack(UNPACK_FORMAT_STR) }
  scan_it { STR.scan(/.{1,3}/) }
end
# >> Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> unpack2 is similar to unpack1
# >> unpack1 is faster than scan_it by 3x ± 0.1
```

Notice that Fruity reduced the number of tests. The delta between the two `unpack*` tests would have been greater if there were more loops and Fruity would have reflected a similar difference as in the first tests. In either case, `scan` still would have trailed.

Answer (score 1):

I think [String#scan (mentioned by Yu)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28768227/3109182) is the best way.  Another "ruby" way to do it that is clearly more verbose:

```
[5] pry(main)> str
=> "AUGCUGAUGCCUAGUCUG"
[6] pry(main)> str.chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join)
=> ["AUG", "CUG", "AUG", "CCU", "AGU", "CUG"]
```

Answer (score -1):

int len = str.length();
        int arrLen = len/3;

```
    String arr[] = new String[arrLen];

    int k=0;
    for(int i=3;i<=len;i+=3)
    {
        arr[k] = str.substring(i-3, i);
        k++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```